# How to write kusto query to display resource type like in Azure

Tags: azure, kusto-explorer, azure-resource-graph

When I go to the Azure portal to display the resources in the resource group, the list of types would look like:
[image]

I ran the following Kusto query in the Azure Resource Graph Explorer to obtain the resources in the subscription:

```
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
) on $left.subscriptionId == $right.subscriptionId
| project id, name, type, location, resourceGroup, name1
| where resourceGroup == 'wp-production-dynamicsnavaddons'
| order by name asc
```

The results will display the type as (these were exported into a CSV file):

[image]

I can assume that the value of "microsoft.web/sites" from Kusto is "App Service" in the portal. But we have a lot of resources in Azure and I don't want to match them 1 by 1. I was wondering is there a way in Kusto Query to display the Type like what's in the portal? (display "App Service" instead of "microsoft.web/sites").

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn on the "Formatted results" in Azure Resource Graph Explorer. This will format the results both in browser and in the exported CSV-file.

In the portal:
[image: Azure Resource Explorer screenshot]

And in the exported CSV:

```
"NAME","TYPE","LOCATION","RESOURCE GROUP","NAME1"
"Failure Anomalies - devenvpocfunc","Smart detector alert rule","Global","gammaray-devenvpoc3","Visual Studio Professional Subscription"
"devenvpocfunc","Application Insights","West Europe","gammaray-devenvpoc3","Visual Studio Professional Subscription"
"devenvpocfunc","Storage account","West Europe","gammaray-devenvpoc3","Visual Studio Professional Subscription"
"devenvpocfunc","App Service plan","West Europe","gammaray-devenvpoc3","Visual Studio Professional Subscription"
"devenvpocfunc","App Service","West Europe","gammaray-devenvpoc3","Visual Studio Professional Subscription"
```

Comment: Hi @bursson, thanks for the tip. I changed the setting and it worked.